# How to use one variable in more function in one controller in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have controller that has functions and I want to use one variable through them

```
class TrainerController extends \BaseController {
  public function one(){
    $variable = "some data";
  }

  public function two()
  {
    //How to use $variable here ?!
  }
}
```

I tried to use session but session scope in one function (view) only
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Make it a property

```
class TrainerController extends \BaseController 
{

  private $variable;

  public functionOne(){
    $this->variable = "some data";
  }

  public functionTwo()
  {
    echo $this->variable; //outputs 'some data' IF this 1st method has already been called
  }
}
```

Comment: I did that, but still not worked

Comment: Please explain, do you mean you need to make it available across requests?

Comment: Then you need to save it to persistant storage. Sessions seem like the obvious choice - what problem did you encounter when you tried to do that?

Comment: I use Session::put but when I get it , It's undefined variable in session

Comment: Are you certain the 1st method (function one) is being called before the second one? Also, it the same user accessing both, because sessions are unique to each user

Comment: see the $variable has common data that is important for all functions in this controller , got it ?